# what element triggers a page exit

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, window.onunload

I'm trying to find the element that triggered a page exit. Say they click on an a href... I'll leave the JS-initiated location changes for another battle. I want to do some processing before exit (ie, save state of app).

What I've tried:

```
$(window).bind("unload", function(e) { console.log("====EXIT===="); console.log($(this)); console.dir(e); } );
```

Neither the $(this) nor "e" (event) reference the element that caused it.

- $(this) is nothing
- and "e" prints an empty object "c.Event"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i pressume this one will work for you.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('a').click(function(event){
        var pageUrl = $(this).attr("href");
        if(pageUrl.indexOf('google.com') == -1 && !$(this).attr("rel") && pageUrl.indexOf('javascript')==-1){
            //only your domain, lightboxes, and javascripts, otherwise cancel event.
            event.preventDefault(); 
            console.log('sorry dude no another site');
        }
    });

});
```

Try with theese;

```
<a href="http://google.com">google</a>
<a href="http://yahoo.com">another site</a>
<a href="javascript:alert(1)">alert</a>
<a href="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/b46c1b6ff31e665600a62482f197622f?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG" rel="ligthbox">image</a>
```

Comment: Went with a variation of this since unload and beforeunload were just too quirky

Comment: yes it's because sometimes browsers can skip unload / beforeunload events and you may want to use your own box etc.

Answer (score 0):

The JavaScript event is "onBeforeUnload" and its corresponding jQuery event is 'beforeunload':

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function() {
  confirm("You know you're leaving this page, right?");
});
```

**EDIT** -

The only way to determine which element caused a URL change is to hook all of the elements on the page. For example:

```
var lastElementClicked;

$('a').click(function(){
  lastElementClicked = this;
});
```

You can then use the `lastElementClicked` object's attributes -- such as `href`, `data()` or `html()` -- in the `beforeUnload` to do your logic.

Comment: Yeah, tried that one too, but for some reason it fires the event twice so I went back to just unload, and still no scope to the initiating element (i.e., "Which Link")

Comment: Yeah, previous thought I had. Was hoping for something a bit cleaner. Will try this, but keep post open for a bit in hopes someone knows some super secret way to do it with the event object itself.